# Does browser.wait inside a method mean that method needs to be async..?

Tags: angular, typescript, selenium, protractor

I'm a newbie to typescript, so please be gentle.  I'm doing a bit of refactoring to some selenium tests using protractor and angular.

I've created a method to wrap

```
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element));
```

My tests were all green (when the code above was inline rather than extracted to a method, but now they seem to be failing.  Does the extracted method below need to be async as browser.wait returns a promise..?

```
async waitForAsync(element) {
    browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element));
}
```

[Edit]

So if I have a method getElementText()

```
getElementText(element){ 
  return element.getText(); // getText returns a promise 
}
```

I just want to be able to call it like this

```
const myText = getElementText(element);
```

and have it return the text, rather than the promise. Would I make this method async?

Answer (score 0):

No. Function needs to be `async` only when you want to `await` an expression inside the function's body.

Comment: Yes, I mean specifically the `await` keyword. That's why the back ticks.

Comment: When you say only when I want to await an expression, do you mean that it only needs to be async when I use the await keyword within that method?  

So if I have method1 

       method1(element){
           return element.getText();   // getText returns a promise
        }

I just want to be able to call it like this

   const myText = method1(element);

and have it return the text, rather than the promise.  Would I make this method async?

Comment: Sorry, can't work out how to format a comment - added the formatted question to the original question.

Comment: If you want your driver calls to happen in a certain order, you need to await all async calls.  (Or don't use async at all...)  In general any webdriver command should happen in sequence... because the next action or actions could affect the DOM or create stale references to the DOM.  A webdriverwait would be particularly vulnerable because it is polling in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to make the statement await to get the value if you don't want to use promise.

```
    const myText = await getElementText(element);
```

Also ensure that function enclosing it is async().

Comment: Thank you.  And for the first method


async waitForAsync(element) {
    browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element));
}

Does that also need to be async?

Comment: Yes because in selenium we want to run synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you cheers.

Pages file

[image]

Spec file

[image]